# How Can I test my website using selemium Grid?

Tags: selenium-grid

I want to use selenium grid for my web page testing. I have successfully installed the demo of selenium grid on my PC and it is running fine.
I have followed  this [link](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/run_the_demo.html) to install and run the selenium grid demo.

I am trying to code a java program using selenium rc which can run with selenium grid for testing the web site, but I am not getting how does I make change on the selenium grid existing demo so that it will work for my web test.

Can some body provide me any link/example so that I will do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of SUT written in ASP.NET, tests based on selenium and build scripts which allow to run tests with selenium-grid:

http://code.google.com/p/design-of-selenium-tests-for-asp-net/

Comment: Thanks for the link ,Can you please provide me a java code for that?
I am not able to code in .net.

Comment: Here is the example of Selenium tests for Java : http://www.bitmotif.com/selenium/selenium-remote-control-for-java-a-tutorial/. You can run them in selenium grid using TestNG